# How do I create a node.js command line utility that uses gulp

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, gulp

I've been working on a command line tool that is essentially a customized setup of gulp plus a custom gulp plugin. For a variety of reasons, I'd like to be able to kick off this process from within another Node application or from the command line. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gulpfiles are just node apps. You can require them in your node app like any module:

```
var gulpfile = require('./gulpfile.js');
```

Then you can invoke a gulp task that was defined in the gulpfile:

```
gulp.start('someTask');
```

*Note that `.start()` will be [deprecated in gulp 4.0](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md#gulpparalleltasks)*

Putting that all together, it would look something like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
require('./gulpfile');

gulp.start('someTask');
```

Alternately, you can use [Node Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) `.spawn()` method to invoke gulp, however this can be a bit trickier. Here's a sample script:

```
'use strict';

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var cwd = process.env.PWD || process.cwd();

var gulpProc = spawn('gulp', ['taskName'], {
  stdio: 'inherit',
  cwd: cwd
});

gulpProc.on('close', function (code) {
  process.exit(code);
});

// catch exceptions so node doesn't exit prematurely, leaving a runaway process
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
   console.error(err.stack);
   gulpProc.kill('SIGHUP');
});
```

Comment: This is working great, thank you! I even was able to export gulp from the gulpfile.js and then run gulp.start('someTask') from my main Node file. One thing I noticed is that the command line output doesn't come through this way. Any thoughts on why that might be the case?

Comment: Not sure what you can do to fix that. Haven't looked into it myself.

Comment: Absolutely, just wanted to make a small edit to help make things clearer. I solved my issue by exporting gulp and then I can programmatically execute gulp as I need to. Thanks!